# design low pass filter

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

Let us suppose that we have signal

```
>> fs=100;

>> ts=1/fs;
>> t=0:ts:2.93;

>> x=23*sin(2*pi*30*t)+22*cos(2*pi*51*t)+24*sin(2*pi*15*t)+6*randn(size(t));
```

Because one frequency is high then sampling frequency divided by two, I want to apply low pass filter to that all frequency that are below 50 should stay unchanged, but all others should be removed, so I have tried:

```
>> fc=50;
>> wn=(2/fs)*fc;
>> b=fir1(20,wn,'low',kaiser(21,3));
```

but this command

```
fvtool(b,1,'fs',fs)
```

the generates error:

**Coefficients must be finite.**

Also the command

```
y = filter(b,1,x); removes all frequency components from  signal,what is problem?
```

Answer (score 3):

The coefficients in `b` are all `NaN`.  This is because your cutoff frequency is set to 1, the Nyquist frequency, but according to the [`fir1` help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir1.html):

```
The cut-off frequency Wn must be between 0 < Wn < 1.0, with 1.0 corresponding to half 
the sample rate.
```

There's no point to setting the cutoff to 1.0 with a low-pass filter since it would be designed to pass all frequencies.

Anyway, normalized frequencies go from 0 to fs/2, so if you want to pass below 50, your job is done since that's the Nyquist rate when the sampling rate is 100 Hz.  Frequencies above 50 Hz cannot be represented in a discrete representation with a 100 Hz fs.  Ideally *you'd filter out high frequencies before discretization/sampling*.

Comment: @datodatuashvili Pick an appropriate Wn or _don't filter at all_.  With a sampling rate of 100 Hz, you can only represent frequencies up to 50 Hz from the start.

Comment: i am doing just practice, let us suppose 51 is  frequency so i want to rmeove

Comment: @datodatuashvili please read wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency

Comment: you dont understand, i need implement grammatically, not theoretically i know what does it mean

Comment: @datodatuashvili I think it's you who don't understand: if your sampling frequency is 100Hz, **you can't represent (and therefore filter) anything above 50Hz**.

Comment: no my friend  it is not me, i am not talking that i can represent, i want to implement low pass filter so that all frequency above 50 will be removed, i need just code for it ok?i wrote some code and there is mistake please help me

Comment: i understand everything myself,but  thanks anyway for your help